# Sending Outlook Emails via R workaround on OSX

Tags: r, rstudio, rdcomclient

I've looked throughout the site but have not been able to find an answer.

I need to use R to send emails via my works outlook email. It has to be from Outlook, not anywhere else.

Problem is, the computer I'm using is OSX so `RDCOMClient` won't work.

EDIT: Tried this and it wouldn't work.

```
sender<-"myemail@outlook.com"
recipients<-c("myemail@outlook.com")
send.mail(from = sender, to = recipients,
          subject = "Test",
          body = BodyOfMessage,
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp-mail.outlook.com"),
          authenticate = FALSE,
          html = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)Does anyone have a workaround?
```

And it resulted in this error:

> org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the
>   following server failed : smtp-mail.outlook.com:25    at
>   org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)    at
>   org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386) Caused by:
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was
>   not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM
>   [BN6PR19CA0117.namprd19.prod.outlook.com]
>
> at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2202)
>     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1693)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1194)
>     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.jaNULL va:254)  at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)     at
>   org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)    ... 6
>   more Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following
>   server failed : smtp-mail.outlook.com:25

Comment: Probably no longer relevant for you, but for anyone else who comes across this - the starting point would probably have to be AppleScript (https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/360677), which currently only works after reverting to the legacy outlook.

Answer (score 1):

So, you wouldn't necessarily be sending this through your Outlook client, which is all that Outlook is. You would want to allow the R script you write and the libraries employed to be an email client. I use mailR with a lot of success. Some people like sendmailR for sending messages. They both have their advantages. Your email administrator might allow unauthenticated sending if you run a lot of scripting from a host. Or you can authenticate in your script.
For example:

```
library(mailR)
#################
# Generate Spam #
#################
BodyOfMessage <- paste("<html><body><p>Hello,</p><p>This is an email message.</p>
                      <hr>
                      <p>The second table is a list of users that need to be toggled in the system, by adding them to the correct securitygroup.</p>
                      <p>", toggle.these.people, "</p>
                      <p>Scott</p></body></html>")
#mailR
    sender<-"fromwho@fromyou.org"
    recipients<-c("emailtosendto@email.com")
    send.mail(from = sender, to = recipients,
    subject = paste("Blah. Created: today.", sep = ""),
    body = BodyOfMessage,
    smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.exchangeserver.org"),
    authenticate = FALSE,
    html = TRUE,
    attach.files = CSVFileNameIs,    
    send = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by `You would want to allow the R script you write and the libraries employed to be an email client`?

Comment: No problem. Instead of using a mail client such as Outlook, let the R script and the library be the client. The mailR or sendmailR package (others exist too) negotiate with the server, acting as the client. Your script supplies the correct parameters, such as the smtp address, message, subject, from, to, credentials.....

Comment: Thanks. I just posted some changes in my original post using what you gave me. I take it I just need to get my authentication permissions changed?

Comment: https://github.com/rpremraj/mailR has a few examples of authenticated sending. Based on this message, authentication is the issue, so either authenticate in your script, or get the mail admin to allow unauthenticated sending from certain hosts.

Answer (score 0):

For the record (because I could not find a current solution): sending emails from R through Outlook is possible with Applescript. For that, Outlook currently needs to be reverted to the legacy version, though the New Outlook is supposed to support it soon.

Then you need an Applescript function saved in a file. This version accepts multiple To recipients - it could obviously be extended for CC, attachments, etc.

```
on run argv
    set varSubject to item 1 of argv
    set varContent to item 2 of argv
    set shouldSend to item 3 of argv
    set recipientDetails to items 4 through end of argv

    tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
        set newMail to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:varSubject, content:varContent}

        repeat with i from 1 to (count recipientDetails) by 2
            set varName to item i of recipientDetails
            set varEmail to item (i + 1) of recipientDetails
            make new recipient at newMail with properties {email address:{name:varName, address:varEmail}}
        end repeat

        if shouldSend is "true" then
            tell newMail to send
        end if
    end tell
end run
```

Then this can be called from R like this

```r
send_email <- function(subject, content, names, emails, send = FALSE) {
    script_path <- "applescript_send_email.scpt"  # Update with the correct path to your script
    send_flag <- ifelse(send, "true", "false")

    # Combine names and emails
    recipient_args <- mapply(function(name, email) c(shQuote(name), shQuote(email)), names, emails, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
    recipient_args <- unlist(recipient_args)

    args <- c(shQuote(subject), shQuote(content), send_flag, recipient_args)
    system2("osascript", args = c(script_path, args), wait = FALSE)
}

send_email("Hello again", "<b>Good</b>Bye", c("Jon Snow", "Arya Stark"), c("jsnow@castleblack.org", "astark@winterfell.com"), TRUE)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what I use and it works fine for me.

```
library(RDCOMClient)
## init com api
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
## create an email 
outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
## configure  email parameter 
outMail[["To"]] = "ryanshuell@gmail.com"
outMail[["subject"]] = "some subject"
outMail[["body"]] = "some body"
## send it                     
outMail$Send()
```

Comment: "This is a Windows-specific package" - so unfortunately won't work for the RP (and me) who are looking for an OSX solution.